# Better approach to perform some sql tasks daily in a storm application?

Tags: sql-server, apache-storm

What will be a better approach if I want to create an SQL table daily into which I insert data via my storm application:

1. run a cron daily to create the table on the server
2. Use tick tuples in the storm bolt to create a new table after every 24 hours.

or some other better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we want to perform the sql table creation task at a specified time of the day, then cron job is a better option, otherwise tick tuple would do.

I went ahead with the first option for my use case.